# Extract entire text from PDF with iTextSharp

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext

I'm trying to parse [PDF documents](http://s23.postimg.org/cfhm80kor/cats.jpg) in order for certain values be added to an existing database. The problem is with parsing the PDF.

### First try

```
String[] AllPdf = Directory.GetFiles(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "*.pdf", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
        foreach (var pdfDoc in AllPdf)
        {
            using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfDoc))
            {
                for (int page = 1; page <= reader.NumberOfPages; page++)
                {
                    ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new LocationTextExtractionStrategy();
                    String text = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, page, strategy);
                }
                
            }
        }
```

But unfortunately that only parsed the text after the titles (Employer, Website, Language etc). And I need the titles in order to create a class which will be mapped to a relation in the database.

### Second try

```
String[] AllPdf = Directory.GetFiles(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "*.pdf", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
        foreach (var pdfDoc in AllPdf)
        {
            using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfDoc))
            {
                for (int page = 1; page <= reader.NumberOfPages; page++)
                {
                    byte[] streamBytes = reader.GetPageContent(page);
                    PRTokeniser tokenizer = new PRTokeniser(new RandomAccessFileOrArray(new RandomAccessSourceFactory().CreateSource(streamBytes)));
                    while (tokenizer.NextToken())
                    {
                        if (tokenizer.TokenType == PRTokeniser.TokType.STRING)
                        {
                            String text = tokenizer.StringValue;
                        }
                    }
                }
                
            }
        }
```

Fortunately, this parsed the missing titles, but it parsed them first (words in new lines instead of single line) and the value afterwards.

### iTextSharp documentation?

There must be classes in iTextSharp which can find the titles/values pair. Or at least parse the titles in readable format. I am happy to write my own implementation of `ITextExtractionStrategy`.

Comment: You will find dozens of questions similar to this on SO but I'll repeat the answer we give everyone. PDFs don't have "titles" or "tables" or "headers" or "footers". They don't even have "paragraphs" or "sentences" or "words". They just have characters, lines and images that happen to be in places that match a pattern you expect. Further, there's no guarantee that text is written from left to right, top to bottom in the PDF. The `LocationTextExtractionStrategy` attempts to solve this for you by figuring out the logical order of things. If you provide a sample PDF we can help you more.

Answer (score 0):

iTextSharp does not have an official documentation page, but you can find some answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/itext) on SO. Instead of getting the data from the PDF in a String, try parsing it as XML and then use XPath to get the data you need. Or you can use Linq to XML. I'm guessing that each page in the PDF has the same format, so the XML structure can have the same format as well.

Here is a project sample using [iTextSharp](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14170/Extract-Text-from-PDF-in-C-NET) and [here](https://bytescout.com/products/developer/pdfextractorsdk/index.html) is a SDK (paid) taht you can use, but if you want it free it's a temporary solution.

Comment: iTextSharp is the .Net port of the Java iText. The port is pretty much one-for-one so the Java documentation works very well. You just have to change "Java-isms" to ".Net-isms" like `get/set` Java methods to .Net properties and upper case the first letter of method names. http://itextpdf.com/api